# How do I use a local variable and a temporary variable in a for loop to receive two return values from a function in go?

Tags: go

```
func TwoResults() (int, int) {
    return 0, 0
}

func ForStructure() int {
    var a int
    for a, b := TwoResults(); a == 0 && b == 0; {
        return b
    }
    return a
}
```

In ForStructure function, I'd like to declare a local variable and use it to receive one value from the TwoResults function in the for loop. At the same time, I use a temporary variable to receive another value.

But I can only use ":=" , this turns a variable into a temporary variable.

Also, I don't want to change my code like this:

```
func ForStructure() int {
    var a int
    for _, b := TwoResults(); a == 0 && b == 0; {
        return b
    }
    a, _ = TwoResults()
    return a
}
```

Comment: btw, there are no globals in this example. Both vars are local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code like this instead:

```golang
    var a int
    var b int
    for a, b = TwoResults(); a == 0 && b == 0; {
        return b
    }
    return a
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't want to declare a new global variable.

Comment: @419SUV It's a local variable, not global.

Comment: I see. How about not using local variable，just using temporary variable

Comment: @419SUV There's no such thing as a "temporary" variable. Anyhow, it doesn't work the way you want it to work, as you correctly noted. So you'll have to choose one of the ways on this page which you dislike the least. I don't think there are any other options.

Comment: @419SUV `var a int; a = foo` is identical to `a := foo`

Answer (score 1):

Declare both variables and use `=`:

```
    var a,b int
    for a, b = TwoResults(); a == 0 && b == 0; {
      ...
    }
```